# Django loses session data

Tags: django, session

This is a very strange phenomenon which i have.
My site works properly most of the time. But, from time to time (in the same session), some session info is not saved.

i've added at the end of my view:

```
request.session.modified = True
```

and in my settings, added:

```
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```

Also tried in the view:

```
request.session.save()
```

Still - nothing helps. From time to time, session information is not stored.
i look at the Dbase and i see that it is indeed not saved.

im using django session with cached_db and PickleSerializer.
Any idea?

To answer Iain - Below is the full session settings. but i also tried with file based session - same results.

```
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
CACHES = {
 'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
 }
```

}

also tried with other caches settings or no settings using the default:

```
CACHES = {
  'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
    'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
  }
}
```

The view has lost of logic in it. It ends with:

```
request.session.modified = True
my_logger.debug('question_list is %s' % request.session.get('question_list')) # the list exists 
return HttpResponse(template_block)
```

Comment: Can you give an example view and user journey where the session is not saved?

Comment: Its part of a complex session...  ill try to give the gist of it. The site is an educational site for teachers and students.  One of the flows where it happens is when a student starts a new "game". the system selects questions to be used and keeps the list in an array in the session. 
Then, each time the students presses "next", the next question in the list if displayed.
i keep in the session the list of questions, the question number within the game, the game ID and more.
Sometimes, the list of questions is not saved (in the log i see that the list was updated).

Comment: Can you add that view to the question? Can you also add your session settings?

Comment: How is your app deployed? Do you have multiple workers/processes and you're using `LocMemCache` ?

Comment: i tried different caching options (actually, i normally run with memcache) -i added this to the question.
The deployment is a Docker running on Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you set session expiration time? Also third party packages or other might affect it. Did you check it properly all possibilities

Comment: This is not related to session expiration - it happens (when t happens - only from time to time) when requests are sent one after the other. i also see that the view method is running and preforming all its tasks.
As for packages - i use some packages. But again - it is working fine ~95% of the time, so not sure what to look for in packages..

Comment: maybe you have a bug in the logic that doesn't save the session in the end or saves `None`(s), empty dicts/lists etc.?

Comment: It may be a bug but i dont have an idea what bug can cause such a behavior. 
Notice that the seesion value is correct just before the HttpResponse  (i see it in the log) and then i use the normal HttpResponse method.
Also keep in mind that it works most of the time (this does not mean its not a bug, only that its not something in the logic or the flow)

Comment: It has to be a concurrency problem. Do you have any mechanism to ensure consistence?

Comment: I'm not sure what mechanism you refer to.  can you give an example to such?

i count on the session management to ensure separation between users and to save session information.
i suspected there may be an issue of 2 almost concurrent calls in the same session. But - i managed to re-created the problem also when the next call was delayed to a long time after the first one (that does not save the session to the DB) finished. so this is not the case. Will be happy to see if there is a mechanism you recommend,

Answer (score 0):

I did in fact have the same problems and also tried to save the session properly with the tweaks you posted.

In the end, what solved my problem was changing the default cache in settings.py to

'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',

Comment: How reliable is the dummy cache?